# Bad Argument Type - +

Tags: lisp

I've been getting this error message when I try to run the following code

```
(defun sa (L) 
  (cond
  ((equal '+ (car L)) (soma (nth 0 L) (nth 2 L)))
  (T (sa (cdr L)))
))
```

The objective of this code is to sum two numbers (position 0 and 2 in the list I'm using). L is a list defined using

```
(setq a (list 1 '+ 2))
;also the soma function
(soma (a b) (+ a b))
```

I understand that this is supposed to create the list (1 + 2). I know the problem is the way L comes back after the first pass because the equal is not returning true but I don't know how to fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is `(soma (a b) (+ a b))` supposed to be `(defun soma (a b) (+ a b))`.  It's important to show us the *actual* code you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're accessing the wrong element for the comparison, try this instead:

```
(equal '+ (car (cdr L)))
```

Comment: It worked, thanks man! Can you explain why can't I use only (car L)? isn't this supposed to return the first element of the list?

Comment: @CelsoShigaki that's right, but clearly you're interested in the _second_ element of the list, which is the one that represents the operator. Hence, we do a `cdr` to go to the next list and a `car` to obtain its first element. Alternatively, we could write `(nth 1 L)`